# Using Metadata or Tooling api to get Custom Application's association with Custom Fields and Custom Objects?

Tags: metadata-api, tooling-api

If anyone know if we can using the metadata api or tooling api from SFDC to find all dependency around the custom app in SFDC.

Looking to see we can see all custom setting that has been configured in a single view.  (e.g Record type, custom fields, custom objects that are shown on the app)

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **MetadataComponentDependency (Beta)** object. It has dependency maintained. You can query for dependency.

**Link for the documentation** -
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm